# Is the visual similarity of the simplifications 華→华 and 畢→毕 a coincidence?

Tags: characters, simplified-characters, traditional-characters, traditional-vs-simplified, character-components

華 and 畢 are very similar, the bottom is the same, and only the top 4/5 of their strokes differ.

Their simplifications 华 and 毕 are also similar, the bottom and the top rights are the same and, and the top lefts have the same number of strokes. Both tops now serve as phonetic components, but still look very similar.

Is this a coincidence or was there a strategy?

Comment: To clarify, are you trying to ask if 華 and 畢 are related?

Comment: @drooze No, I'm asking about whether there was a conscious effort to simplify them in visually similar ways, because they were visually similar in traditional.

Comment: The population size of the data of this question is 2 (there looks to be only 2 characters which look like the bottom of 華 and 畢 which were simplified, and those are the two characters), and the question asks if there is a pattern or if this is a coincidence. Unfortunately I don't think this can be answered.

Comment: Look at this pairs: 攏->拢, 擾->扰.

Answer (score 1):

I think they just, by coincidence, happen to look similar, (to some people I suppose) In any case they sound completely different from each other with no similarity in meaning.

Just like 友 & 发.

Answer (score 0):

No, if you speak them out, they're not the same.

The way how the china simplified 華 to 华 is by pronouncement. 华 can be split into "化" and "十". but you will use top part "化(Hua')" to pronounce it, "十" is just a dummy to make it different between the actual word "化".

So the 畢 and 毕.